# unable to get go package from private github repository

Tags: bash, go, ssh, package, token

Had this working perfectly before I had my computer refreshed, now I now am unable to pull packages from my orgs private github repository. At this time I only need an ssh private key to clone the repository, i am not aware of any 2fA requirement. I have spent hours already trying to resolve this, from what i read this is what I think should work, omitting sensitive variable values.

Error i was getting was unknown versions, but I changed some stuff and now i am getting "ssh: Could not resolve hostname".

```
    #!/bin/bash
    export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
    export GOBIN="$HOME/go/bin"
    export GOPRIVATE="github.com/${GITHUB_ORG}"
    
    go env -w GO111MODULE="on"
    go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/${GITHUB_ORG}"
    
    git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
    
    pushd ~/.ssh
       eval $(ssh-agent);
       ssh-add "${GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH}"
    popd
    
    go get package "github.com/${GITHUB_ORG}/${GITHUB_REPO}/${GO_PACKAGE}"
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `go get -v {package}`? Should provide verbose output which might have some clues

Answer (score 0):

The command you posted is missing the `url.ssh` in the git config.

You can try by changing `git` to use ssh instead of https so that you can fetch private go repositories using `go get`.

Suggestion -

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```